# Is there a scala spark function to achieve the groupby then filter and then aggregate

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science

I have a Dataframe with the list of state and salary list in the state.I need to group by state and find out how many entries are there in each of the salary range(there are 3 salary ranges in total) create a Dataframe and sort the result based on state name . Is there any function in Spark which will achieve this.

```
Sample input 

State  salary
------ ------
NY      6
WI      15
NY      11
WI      2
MI      20
NY      15 
 
Result expected is

State    group1   group2  group3
 MI         0       0       1  
 NY         0       1       2
 WI         1       0       1
```

Where

- Group1 is count of salary  > 0 and <= 5
- Group2 is count of salary > 5 and <=10
- Group3 is count of salary >10 and <=20

basically looking from something like in scala spark

```
df.groupBy('STATE').agg(count('*') as group1).where('SALARY' >0 and 'SALARY' <=5)
.agg(count('*') as group2).where('SALARY' >5 and 'SALARY' <=10)
.agg(count('*') as group3).where('SALARY' >10 and 'SALARY' <=20)
```

**Solution update** :

**Solution1**: was able to resolve as provided below , but not sure if there is a much simpler and efficient way . any direction?
dfWithoutSchema is the input dataframe

```
val newDf = dfWithoutSchema.withColumn("set1", when($"salary">0 and $"salary" <= 5, 1).otherwise(0)).withColumn("set2", when($"salary">5 and $"salary" <= 10, 1).otherwise(0)).withColumn("set3", when($"salary">10 and $"salary" <= 20, 1).otherwise(0))
val fdf=newDf.groupBy("state").agg(sum("set1") as "group1",sum("set2") as "group2",sum("set3") as "group3").sort("state")
```

**Solution 2**:

```
val agg_df = df.groupBy("State")
    .agg(
        count(when($"Salary" > 0 && $"Salary" <= 5, $"Salary")).as("group_1"),
        count(when($"Salary" > 5 && $"Salary" <= 10, $"Salary")).as("group_2"),
        count(when($"Salary" > 10 && $"Salary" <= 20, $"Salary")).as("group_3")
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify condition on which you want to `count`/`sum` in aggregate.

Example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"State": "NY", "Salary": 6},
    {"State": "WI", "Salary": 15},
    {"State": "NY", "Salary": 11},
    {"State": "WI", "Salary": 2},
    {"State": "MI", "Salary": 20},
    {"State": "NY", "Salary": 15},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data)
cnt_cond = lambda cond: F.sum(F.when(cond, 1).otherwise(0))
df = df.groupBy("State").agg(
    cnt_cond((F.col("Salary") > 0) & (F.col("Salary") <= 5)).alias("group_1"),
    cnt_cond((F.col("Salary") > 5) & (F.col("Salary") <= 10)).alias("group_2"),
    cnt_cond((F.col("Salary") > 10) & (F.col("Salary") <= 20)).alias("group_3"),
)
```

Here `sum` is the same as `count` since it checks the condition and returns `1` if condition is met, otherwise `0`.

Using Scala:

```scala
val agg_df = df.groupBy("State")
    .agg(
        count(when($"Salary" > 0 && $"Salary" <= 5, $"Salary")).as("group_1"),
        count(when($"Salary" > 5 && $"Salary" <= 10, $"Salary")).as("group_2"),
        count(when($"Salary" > 10 && $"Salary" <= 20, $"Salary")).as("group_3")
    )
```

Result:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+                                                 
|State|group_1|group_2|group_3|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|NY   |0      |1      |2      |
|WI   |1      |0      |1      |
|MI   |0      |0      |1      |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I was looking to do this in Scala spark.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad siv .was able to get the results and updated the main thread .but not sure if there is a much simpler way to do it

Comment: @Krish You're welcome. Updated the answer to include the same example but in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression composed of `sum` and `case` functions.

```
data = [
    ('NY', 6),
    ('WI', 15),
    ('NY', 11),
    ('WI', 2),
    ('MI', 20),
    ('NY', 15)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['State', 'salary'])
df = df.groupBy('State').agg(F.expr('sum(case when salary>0 and salary<=5 then 1 else 0 end)').alias('group1'),
                             F.expr('sum(case when salary>5 and salary<=10 then 1 else 0 end)').alias('group2'),
                             F.expr('sum(case when salary>10 and salary<=20 then 1 else 0 end)').alias('group3'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing @过过招. I was looking to do this in Scala spark.

Comment: Thanks was able to get the results and updated the main thread .but not sure if there is a much simpler way to do it .